# Bootstrap Mobile Menu Opens Behind Brand Img (Using Z Index for Content, Which Works, But not For Oversized Brand IMG)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The site: www.itsolvedmd.com

In mobile view, I cannot get the toggle menu to sit in front of the brand image. Ideally, I'd like to somehow margin or pad the menu to be at the same height of my brand image's bottom edge.

Also, in desktop viewports I'd like my link text to be bigger which I cannot seem to accomplish either.

My CSS:

```
.navbar {
height: 113px;
margin-top: 15px;
}
.navbar-default {
background: transparent;
border: none;
}
.navbar {
z-index: 9999;
padding-top: 20px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a, .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
color: #000;}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
text-decoration: bold; 
color: #39b54a; 
background-color: none;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 766px) {
.collapsing, .in {background-color: #f7f7f7;}
.collapsing ul li a, .in ul li a {color: #555!important;}
.collapsing ul li a:hover, .in ul li a:hover {color: #f1f1f1!important;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.navbar-brand` element has a fixed height of 50px. The logo present has a height of 110px.

The shorthand solution would be to create a new class rule to override and increase the fixed height declared in the CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
  height: 110px;
}
```

Or to make it a little more flexible:

```
.navbar-brand {
  min-height: 110px;
  height: auto;
}
```